# Convert integer back to 32-bit hex representation then to float?

Tags: python

Say I have some binary data that was converted to 32-bit integer instead of 32-bit floating point (little endian), how can I rectify this?

For example: `1155186688` should be `1750` float (`00 C0 DA 44` hex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Struct is used for packing and unpacking types into bytes.

Convert the integer back to bytes, then into a float:

```
struct.unpack('f', struct.pack('I', 1155186688))[0]
```

Or the long form:

```
>>> my_bytes = struct.pack('I', 1155186688) # 'I' = Unsigned Int
b'\x00\xc0\xdaD'
>>> my_float = struct.unpack('f', my_bytes)[0] # 'f' = float
1750
```

Comment: FYI: This returns a tuple.  You (probably) want to stick a `(result,) =` in front of it to unpack that into a reasonable value.

Comment: @Kevin wouldn't `struct.unpack('f', struct.pack('I', 1155186688))[0]` do it too?

Comment: @Aemyl: Yes, but personally I think zero is an ugly magic number in this context.

Comment: And for Python 3, `(1155186688).to_bytes(8, 'little')` can replace the `struct.pack()`, although there doesn't seem to be a corresponding `float.from_bytes()`...